# AngularJs call controller function from factory

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I'm trying a `sample with angularJs` where I'm trying to `call a factory method` and in the factory method, I'm doing an `ajax callback` to get result from database and in the `success event` of the ajax callback, I need to call a `function in the controller` to bind the `result to the UI`.

**My Angular Code:**

```js
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
  .controller('TasksListCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$routeParams', 'Task',
    function($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams, Task) {
      debugger;

      //factory call
      Task.query({
        MobileNumber: $routeParams.MobileNumber,
        ClientCode: $routeParams.ClientCode
      });

      $rootScope.UserMobileNumber = $routeParams.MobileNumber;

      $scope.BindTasksList = function(resultData) {
        debugger;
        $scope.Tasks = resultData;
        $scope.$apply();
      }

    }
  ]);
```

**My Angular Factory Code:**

```js
'use strict';

(function() {

  function GetTasks(MobileNumber, ClientCode) {
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
      url: '/api/TasksAPI/GetTasksList',
      type: 'GET',
      datatype: 'json',
      data: {
        'MobileNumber': MobileNumber,
        'ClientCode': ClientCode
      },
      success: function(response) {
        debugger;
        $scope.BindTasksList(response);
      },
      error: function(xhr) {}
    });
  };

  angular.module('myApp.DbScripts', [])
    .factory('Task', [
      function() {
        return {
          query: function(data) {
            debugger;
            GetTasks(data.MobileNumber, data.ClientCode);
          }
        }
      }
    ]);
}());
```

**My app.js Code:**

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngTouch',
  'ngRoute',
  'ngAnimate',
  'myApp.controllers',
  'myApp.DbScripts'
]).
config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    debugger;
    $routeProvider.when('/tasks/:MobileNumber/:ClientCode', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/tasks-list.html',
      controller: 'TasksListCtrl'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/tasks/:taskId', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/task-details.html',
      controller: 'TaskDetailCtrl'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/tasks/:taskId/status', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/task-completion-details.html',
      controller: 'TaskCompletionDetailCtrl'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/tasks/:taskId/route', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/route-details.html',
      controller: 'RouteDetailCtrl'
    });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/tasks'
    });
  }
]);
```

But, I'm unable to call the function in controller. I've also tried it with `angular.element(document.getElementById('TasksListCtrl')).scope().BindTasksList(response)`. But even that's not working.

Can anyone please point out the mistake I'm doing?
How to send the $scope of the controller to the factory?

Comment: `myApp.DbScripts` is a different module and needs to be added to the controller module: `angular.module('myApp.controllers', ['myApp.DbScripts'])`

Comment: I'm getting this error : `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]`

Comment: Shouldn't the controller be the one calling the factory methods? Not the other way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by leveraging the `$http` promises, in you factory, return the promise instead as follows

```
'use strict';

(function() {

  function GetTasks(MobileNumber, ClientCode) {

  };

  angular.module('myApp.DbScripts', [])
    .factory('Task', [
      function($http) {
        return {
          query: function(data) {
           return $http({
                   url: '/api/TasksAPI/GetTasksList',
                   method: 'GET',
                   params: {
                            'MobileNumber': data.MobileNumber,
                            'ClientCode': data.ClientCode
                           }
                }).then(function(result) {
                   return result;
                });
          }
        }
      }
    ]);
}());
```

Then in your controller you can access the `$http` response object that is returned:

```
      //factory call
      Task.query({
        MobileNumber: $routeParams.MobileNumber,
        ClientCode: $routeParams.ClientCode
      }).then(function(resp) {
           // access $http resp here and attach to $scope.Tasks
      });
```

If you can, I would advocate using `$q` along `$http` as well, so that you do not need to parse through the http response and get a nice little response data object back

[plnk](http://plnkr.co/edit/5FuDshuaPgmPhlGWWEPu?p=preview)

Comment: Hello @Kashyap : Thanks for the reply.
Actually, now I'm getting `$http is not a function` error in factory.

Comment: can you make sure you have injected in the factory function?

Comment: `angular.module('myApp.DbScripts', [])
        .factory('Task', [
            function ($http) {
                return {
                    query: function (data) {                                        
                    }
                }
            }]);`

Comment: I've done this way, but unable to make a call.
Is there any problem with the injection order?

Comment: try `angular.module('myApp.DbScripts', []) .factory('Task', ['$http', function ($http) { return { query: function (data) { } } }]);`

Comment: I've kept a debugger and checked the `$http object in the factory`.but it's showing `$http` as `undefined`

Comment: I updated answer with a working example, take a look

Comment: Your Plunker has  `.factory('Task', [ '$http',`. Also `.then(function(result) {return result;})` is redundant and not needed.